# How to install phonegap to eclipse

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have downloaded the phonene plugin from the svn url provide.
As in post written to install using the SVN url online,
Is there any way to install it by locally?

Comment: Are you talking about the "phonegap plugins" or "Eclipse Phonegap Plugin"?

Comment: Yes, I want ot install phonegap plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is about how to install phonegap plugin to phonegap project. Not to install phonegap plugin to eclipse.

1.cd to your project

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test
```

2.add phonegap plugin into your project

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device
```

Done